# Android image picker for local files only

Tags: android, image, picker, picasa

I'm using the built in Android image picker as follows:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
m_activity.startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, PHOTO_PICKER_ID);
```

Is there any way to restrict this to show only locally available files. On my device it is currently picking up Picasa thumbnails and I'd like to exclude all images that are not actually present on the device.

Comment: Seems you are using some application that had already stored Picasa thumbnails on your sdcard. Code is seems good

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Adding intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true); will allow for local files only.  It will exclude picasa images.  Hope this helps.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
            "Complete action using"), PHOTO_PICKER_ID);
```

Comment: The only problem with the `EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY`flag is it's [only available since Honeycomb](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY). Be sure to make a check of the API before using it.

Comment: It resolves to a constant. In pre-honeycomb you could specify the constant string "android.intent.extra.LOCAL_ONLY"

Comment: How to restrict external sdcard from this intent?

Answer (score -3):

User this code to launch intent to get local image chooser.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                "Complete action using"), PHOTO_PICKER_ID);
```

Comment: does this prevent ppl from selecting from the picasa albums?