# Show only folders in Gallery that are on phone

Tags: android

My app has a built-in cropper. I want the user to select photos from the Gallery but only folders that are on the phone. By default, the Gallery shows all folders including those from PicasaWeb.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an extra to your intent.

`intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);`

[Android image picker for local files only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080109/android-image-picker-for-local-files-only)