# Imagepicker like datepicker in android

Tags: android

Is it possible to make image picker in android like date picker or time picker? Actually i am making an app in which i need to make a image picker from where user can select small image. Like date picker or time picker here in this picker user can scroll and select small images then numbers. Please anybody help me to achieve this.

Comment: I guess you can do this using a `listview` which shows on item a time and resize it accordingly also keep in mind to use `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use UI controller like iphone. Basically you are talking about wheel UI controller of android. Specifically it is not in-built android UI Controller but you have to make it costume. Please check this tutorial is exactly what you want : [Here](http://android-devblog.blogspot.in/2010/05/wheel-ui-contol.html)

Hope you got solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no imagepicker available in android . You can use intent to pick image, Click on the below link [Android image picker for local files only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080109/android-image-picker-for-local-files-only).

Hope it helps.