# image picker for local file only , hide dropbox

Tags: java, android

I am using default image picker to pick photos. I installed dropbox app in my phone.So it shows up together with gallery and photo.Is there way to hide dropbox showing in image picker?I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080109/android-image-picker-for-local-files-only) but it doesn't work for my app.

```
![Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);

                    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose a Picture");
                    ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(chooser, photoGalleryCode);]
```

[android image picker showing dropbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bAmd.png)

Min

Comment: I looked  to the [sourcecode of the imagepicker](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Gallery2/blob/cm-12.0/src/com/android/gallery3d/app/GalleryActivity.java) but didn't find a quick answer. Maybe you have more luck .....

Answer (score 0):

just replace
Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
with
Intent.ACTION_PICK